# Submitting .bar file to BlackBerry store

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-world

I have a .bar file for BB app. This .bar file was created by a fellow developer. Can I publish it using my account?  How to publish it on store?

Answer (score 2):

as long as you have the rights to publish you can create a vendor account for the team you work with.

First of all you will need to set up a Vendor Account to be able to publish to the store. This is a straightforward process however, in order to be verified, you will need to provide some documentation.
You can follow the instructions at 
https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/blackberryworld/apply_for_a_blackberry_world_membership_account.html

Once you have an account (it may take few days to get approved) follow the step-by-step instructions provided at https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/blackberryworld/adding_new_apps_and_digital_goods.html
you should now be able to create a product release with your screenshots and the bar file.

Bear in mind that since your colleague has signed the app, any future release will need to be signed with the same keys. Remember to back up the keys, you can also share the same set keys with other members of the team so that everyone can package future releases.

Cheers,

Luca